# Package ‘git’ has no installation candidate?

Tags: apt, package-management, git

I’m trying to install some dependencies and I get errors. For example, with git, I get “package git has no installation candidate’

With libx11-dev and several other prerequisites, I get “unable to locate package”.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109635/discussion-on-question-by-perplexeddimension-package-git-has-no-installation-c).

Comment: try: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install git` If not, update the question with the output of `lsb_release -a` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score -1):

First of all after installation you have to run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Thi sinitiates your package manager additionaly to keep everything clean

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

No you are ready to go. start by searching the package you want to install

```
sudo apt-cache search git
```

This will bring you the search result and you can do

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

If still appears same error then check for content in apt source file probably in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
However you can always simplify the process by using GUI software called package manager. You can launch that software  by searching in menu.